# Is there any jest matcher to comapare Array<Objects>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to test two array of objects are exactly equal, tried with toEqual matcher but seems it only works for Array of strings, is there any matcher available in Jest to satisfy the condition. please dont mark this as dulplicate , I didn't find an clear answers.

```
const arr1 = [{name: 'sam', degree: 'engineer', age: '23'}, {name: 'jane', degree: 'accounts', age: '25'}]
const arr2 = [{name: 'jane', degree: 'accounts', age: '25'},{name: 'sam', degree: 'engineer', age: '23'}]

expect(arr1).toEqual(arr2)  // should pass the testcase
```

Comment: `toEqual` works fine on arrays of objects as well, but not on arrays whose elements are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it as a series of expectations.

```
expect(arr1).toBeArray();
expect(arr2).toBeArray();
expect(arr1).toBeArrayOfSize(arr2.length);
expect(arr2).toBeArrayOfSize(arr1.length);
```

next loop each array and check if the second contains its element

```
arr1.forEach(item => {
   expect(arr2).toContain(item);
});
```

and

```
arr2.forEach(item => {
   expect(arr1).toContain(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
            const sortResponseData = arr1.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
              return a.name > b.name
                ? 1
                : b.name > a.name
                ? -1
                : 0;
            });
            const sortEntityMetaData = arr2.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
              return a.name > b.name
                ? 1
                : b.name > a.name
                ? -1
                : 0;
            });
            expect(sortResponseData).toEqual(sortEntityMetaData);
```